# Read only Title from a page?

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a page called index.php which has some content on it, but the title is set from another server that generates a text file called cache_currentsongcallapi.txt
Contents of 'cache_currentsongapi.txt':

```
<tracks>
    <radioname>Mick&apos;s Music Station</radioname>
    <rank>0</rank>
    <isradionomy>1</isradionomy>
    <radurl>http://www.radionomy.com/mick-smusicstation</radurl>
    <track>
        <uniqueid>2722440231</uniqueid>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <artists>Adele</artists>
        <starttime>2015-11-23 21:05:02.35</starttime>
        <playduration>293023</playduration>
        <current>1</current>
            <callmeback>217256</callmeback>
    </track>
</tracks>
```

Is there any way that I can take ONLY the title from the text file and display it in the index page?
NOTE:
This method cannot include editing the text file as it is overwritten by the server.

The website that this code will go on: http://mickyd.net/radio

Comment: This txt file can actually be treated and parsed as an XML file. Have you attempted to read the file yet ?

Comment: sorry, chris85, but I have tried that and simply do not get it! Can you explain it to me in simple reference?

Comment: You have tried what exactly? There are 20 different solutions in that dupe. None of them worked for you?

Comment: You have an answer below that should give you a starting point. There are links here and in that thread that should be able to assist you further. If you have a particular issue please post on that topic. Please also use the `@` to tag users, notifications aren't sent otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears like valid XML. Never, **never** read XML using regular expressions. You'll hear this a lot, and for good reasons.

I'd start by reading the string as XML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$result = $xml->xpath('/tracks/track/title');
```

Your mileage may vary, but basically you can do a lot starting from here. I'd suggest reading a bit more on [DOMXPath](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) and [SimpleXMLElement](https://secure.php.net/manual/ro/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Comment: But, do I need to include the txt file and how would I do it?

Comment: Or even just `$result = $xml->track->title;`. @MichaelDavison you walk through the XML tree. `track` is a child of `tracks` and `title` is a child `track`. Since `tracks` is the upper most parent `$xml` starts there.

Comment: Ok, can you please show me how I would use it in my code? Im quite confused... :/ @Victor-Nitu

Comment: `$string` here could, and would be `file_get_contents('cache_currentsongcallapi.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full version including the reading of the actual file since you seem to need help there too, but please mark Victor's as the answer.

```
$filePath = "file.txt";

$handle = fopen($filePath, "r");

$fileContents = fread($handle, filesize($filePath));

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($fileContents);

$title = $xml->xpath("/tracks/track/title");

echo($title[0]);
```

Where "file.txt" is the path to the file.

Comment: You are a life saver! It was excellently explained! Thank You. I would give you an UP if I had enough reputation points.

Comment: or file_get_contents($filePath); would work, not sure which is most performant for your case.